# What could be the cause of my Exotel Passthru URL not returning query params in node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, exotel-api

I have to make a url or API to get the data from Exotel passthru using HTTP get method and the Exotel passtrhu sends the data in query params so I want to get the data from query params and save it in my db
but I didn't understand why the API didn't get any data I can't figure out the problem I already talked to Exotel developers they just provide me a url to use for demo [demo-url](https://test.requestcatcher.com/test) it worked perfectly but when I use my url it didn't work.
please help me to solve this problem

```
app.get('/exotel/connect', (req, res) => {  
const queryParams = req.query;
  console.log('Received query parameters:', queryParams);
  // Process the query parameters here as needed
  res.send('Query parameters received');
});
```

[URl for exotel passthru information](https://support.exotel.com/support/solutions/articles/48283-working-with-passthru-applet)

I tried my url but it didn't work for me.